# Windows Phone 8.1 App is not building on TravisCI server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to get **TravisCI** to build my Windows Phone 8.1 App C# [project](https://github.com/wassim-azirar/GitterClient) (Hosted on Github)

I'm getting this error :

> /home/travis/build/wassim-azirar/GitterClient/GitterClient/GitterClient.csproj
>
> warning : Could not find project file
>
> /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/WindowsXaml/v12.0/Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets
>
> to import. Ignoring.

Full details about the build errors are [here](https://travis-ci.org/wassim-azirar/GitterClient)

My `.travis.yml`

```
language: csharp
solution: GitterClient.sln
env:
  global:
    - EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
sudo: true
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -y gtk-sharp2
  - sudo apt-get install -qq mono-devel > /dev/null
  - mozroots --import --sync
  - export EnableNuGetPackageRestore=true
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release GitterClient.sln
```

I'm getting this error because I'm using the `Behaviours SDK (XAML)` which does not exist in the build server.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.unravelingcode.com/how-to-use-extension-sdks-without-installing-them-in-visual-studio/) (**How to use Extension SDKs without installing them in Visual Studio**). And now my project is building in **[AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/wassim-azirar/gitterclient)** but **not** in **TravisCI**.

I also tried to play with the **.travis.yml** and modified it many times (see file [history](https://github.com/wassim-azirar/GitterClient/commits/master/.travis.yml)) but all my attemps failed and I couldn't make the project build with TravisCI :(

Is there something else I can do to correct this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

*[joshua-anderson](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3859#issuecomment-99248831) :* at the moment, **Travis CI** uses the **mono** on linux, not the official microsoft **.net CLR**, which is windows only. Windows apps **can only** be built on windows with the official .net CLR. Sorry!